# Leaflet Draw Point in Polygon and Add to Editable Layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm having an issue where I can't seem to figure out how to add polygons to editable layer in Leaflet.  Is there a way I can use Leaflet to add a polygon which is user editable?

The other question I have is would it be possible to draw a polygon and while its drawing, show you how many points are inside of that incomplete polygon?

Thanks,

Will

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet provides bunch of [plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#edit-geometries) for creating and editing polygons. My favorite tools as I am using to develop a custom interactive indoor map are,

- [Leaflet Draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw.git) - *Adds functionally and interface for easily creating polyline, polygon, rectangle, circle or marker. And save the feature object to database*
- [Leaflet TileLayer GeoJSON](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson.git) - *To load feature objects' geojson and tile it on layers*

> Is there a way I can use Leaflet to add a polygon which is user
>   editable?
>
> The other question I have is would it be possible to draw a polygon
>   and while its drawing, show you how many points are inside of that
>   incomplete polygon?

Yes, one way is by using this plugin. *(There should be lots of plugin like this one, this just happens to be the one I am using)*

- [Leaflet FreeDraw](https://github.com/Wildhoney/Leaflet.FreeDraw) - *Extension for leaflet draw, and the one that you need if you're talking about editing the geometries*